# MySQL Security Check

Tags: mysql, security

Evening all,

Before i make my site live i obviously want to ensure it's secure (or as secure as possible).

I have a search form, an opportunity for a user to upload an entry to a database, and that's about it i think.

So i just want to check what i should be doing to protect things. Firstly, my database is accessed by a dedicated user account (not admin or root), so i think i've got that part locked down.

Secondly, on all my search queries i have this sort of format:

```
$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE fieldname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($country) . "' 
AND county = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($county) . "'
ORDER BY unique_id DESC");
```

Finally, on the $_POST fields from my submission form, i treat the variables with this BEFORE they are inserted into the database:

```
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($variable);
$result = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO table (columnone)
VALUES ($variable)";
```

Could anyone let me know what else i should be considering or whether this is acceptable enough?

Thanks in advance, as always,
Dan

Comment: You've secured against a single class of attacks, SQL injection through forms. There's nothing more you have to do in that code, but that hardly makes your application or server secure.

Comment: Dan, thanks. So what else do you suggest i should look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, though you should look into using PDO prepared statements if at all possible.

Beyond that, make sure that whatever account your PHP code is using to connect to MySQL has the absolute minimum in the way of permissions. Most web-facing scripts do NOT need alter/drop/create type privileges. Most can get away with only update/insert/select/delete, and maybe even less. This way, even if something goes horribly wrong with your code-level security, a malicious user can't send you a `'; drop table students --` type query (re: [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com))

Comment: Thanks MArc, i'll look into it. I do have an 'edit' section so would that only need Update rather than Alter (i.e. they can only edit their exisiting data rather than add new columns etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you show looks fine in terms of protection against SQL injection, except for

```
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($variable);
$result = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO table (columnone)
VALUES ($variable)";
```

this desperately needs quotes around  `$variable` - or as @Dan points out, a check for whether it's a number - to be secure. `mysql_real_escape_string` sanitizes string data *only* - that means, any attempt to break out of a string delimited by single or double quotes. It provides no protection if the inserted value is not surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Assuming `columnone` is a character field at all. If it's not, the quotes are not appropriate.

Comment: @Dan it doesn't matter, you need to sanitize the variable. I could do anything in `$variable`, like start a sub-select or something. If it's not a character field, you need to make sure it is an `int` (or use quotes - mySQL allows them for any kind of value)

Comment: I did not say the variable need not be sanitized, just that your claim that it *needs* to be quoted in the query is not necessarily appropriate. If it should be a number, you should ensure it's a number, but you should not put quotes around it in the query.

Comment: @Dan fair enough,  I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using like MYSQL PDO and bound parameters in your SQL?

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

My understanding is that this is considerably more secure that using mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: This is not *entirely* true - it is possible to have perfect security with `mysql_real_escape_string`, you just need to know what you're doing. But prepared statements make it harder to overlook things, so there's nothing wrong with using them

Comment: Hi Matt, this is my first dynamic site so to be honest, i've just been trying to get the basics down. A few people have pointed me towards PDO though. Probably next time around :)

Comment: PDO does make life easier, but there are some query constructs that simply cannot work with prepared statements. For those you have to fall back to building your own queries from the ground up and deal with escaping/sanitization on your own.